# Want to use tooltip on office excel ribbon(custom Tab)

Tags: office365, manifest, office-js, ribbon, excel-2016

I have added a menifest.xml file in office add-ins and it is created the custom tab, but now I am using the below code to get the tooltip on that custom tab. This code is not working for me.

```
<Control xsi:type="Button" id="Contoso.FunctionButton">
                  <!--Label for your button. resid must point to a ShortString resource -->
                  <Label resid="Contoso.FunctionButton.Label" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <!--ToolTip title. resid must point to a ShortString resource -->
                    <Title resid="Contoso.FunctionButton.Label" />
                    <!--ToolTip description. resid must point to a LongString resource -->
                    <Description resid="Contoso.FunctionButton.Tooltip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.FunctionButton.Icon" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.FunctionButton.Icon" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.FunctionButton.Icon" />
                  </Icon>
                  <!--This is what happens when the command is triggered (E.g. click on the Ribbon). Supported actions are ExecuteFunction or ShowTaskpane-->
                  <!--Look at the FunctionFile.html page for reference on how to implement the function -->
                  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                    <!--Name of the function to call. This function needs to exist in the global DOM namespace of the function file-->
                    <FunctionName>writeText</FunctionName>
                  </Action>
                </Control>
```

```
<bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="Contoso.FunctionButton.Label" DefaultValue="Execute Function" />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Show Taskpane" />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.Dropdown.Label" DefaultValue="Dropdown" />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.Item1.Label" DefaultValue="Show Taskpane 1" />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.Item2.Label" DefaultValue="Show Taskpane 2" />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.Tab1.GroupLabel" DefaultValue="Test Group" />
         <bt:String id="Contoso.Tab1.TabLabel" DefaultValue="Test Tab" />
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="Contoso.FunctionButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Click to Execute Function" />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Click to Show a Taskpane" />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.Dropdown.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Click to Show Options on this Menu" />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.Item1.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Click to Show Taskpane1" />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.Item2.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Click to Show Taskpane2" />
      </bt:LongStrings>
```

Comment: In what sense does it not work? Do the tooltips not appear? Are you testing with desktop Office or Office Online? On Windows or a Mac?

Comment: we are testing on online (office.com) excel on windows. yes tooltip not appear

Comment: What browser and OS are you on?

Comment: chrome latest version or IE10 and windows 7

Comment: IE 10 is not supported by Office Add-ins. Do you see the tool tip with Chrome on Windows 10?

Comment: I am using windows 7. in this I am not able to see the tooltip, Can you please share the screenshot of tooltip working in chrome with menifest file. if possible please share me the code as well

Comment: I don't have a Windows 7 computer.

Comment: can you please share me only working tooltip screenshot. whether it is windows 7 or 10. it doesnt matter for me. if possible can you please only share me the working code for ribbon tooltip for manifest file.

Comment: @RickKirkham can You please share some sample example code and screenshot of the tooltip, which is working fine for you.